# How to calculate expectation bound?

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am a little doubtful about the last lines which I wrote to complete this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4632926/how-to-prove-the-following-inequality-about-varx/4633367#4633367),

---

**Corrected One**

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n^2} \text{E} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (h(s_i,p_i) - \text{E}[h])^2\right)\right] \text{E} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} z_i^2\right)\right] &\le \frac{1}{n^2} \text{E} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (h(s_i,p_i) - \text{E}[h])^2\right)\right] \left(n\cdot N\right) \\
&\le \frac{1}{n^2} (n \cdot M^2) \cdot (n \cdot N) \\
&\leq M^2 N
\end{align}

The first inequality follows from the fact that $\text{E} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} z_i^2\right)\right] \le n \cdot N$ (since each $z_i^2$ is bounded above by $N$), and the second inequality follows from the fact that $\text{E} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (h(s_i,p_i) - \text{E}[h])^2\right)\right] \le n \cdot M^2$ (since each $|h(s_i,p_i)|$ is bounded above by $M$).

---

My question is like the following

if $Y_i = h(s_i,p_i) - \text{E}[h]$, then $Y_i^2 \ge 0$ and $Y_i^2 \le M^2$, so we have:

\begin{align}
\text{E} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2\right)\right] &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \text{E}[Y_i^2] \\
&\le \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \cdot M^2 \\
&\leq n M^2 \\
\end{align}

So we have $\text{E} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (h(s_i,p_i) - \text{E}[h])^2\right)\right] \le n \cdot M^2$,

**Can one confirm this part to make my answer concrete?**

Comment: If each $z_i^2$ is bounded by $N$ then you can conclude that $\sum_{i=1}^nz_i^2\leq nN$ (so not $\sum_{i=1}^nz_i^2\leq N$). Also: what makes you state that $nM^2\leq M^2$?

Comment: @drhab thanks for your comment. Can you please let me know, if the edited answer seems correct?